# Moving Files into Folders with Exceptions

Tags: bash, shell

I have a set of files in a folder that I move into subfolders based on the files themselves. The file format is:

Name_metadata_metadata_File.ext

Utilizing this line of code:

```
for i in `ls | grep _`; do
    mkdir -p `echo $i | cut -f1 -d "_"`
    mv $i `echo $i | cut -f1 -d "_"`/`echo $i | cut -f5 -d "_"`
    mv $i `echo $i | cut -f1 -d "_"`/`echo $i | cut -f4 -d "_"`
done
```

I have successfully been able to convert it to folder structure:

Name/File.ext

I have now some files with an extra string in the file (Name_str_metadata_metadata_File.ext) and would like to weed those out. I am running into issues of adding an if statement into my line of code:

```
for i in `ls | grep _`; do
    mkdir -p `echo $i | cut -f1 -d "_"`
    if `echo $i | cut -f2 -d "_"` == "str"; then
        mv $i `echo $i | cut -f1 -d "_"`/`echo $i | cut -f5 -d "_"`
    else
        mv $i `echo $i | cut -f1 -d "_"`/`echo $i | cut -f4 -d "_"`
    fi
done
```

Am I writing the if statement incorrectly?

Comment: Is it a *must* to have it in a single line? Moreover, you shouldn't rely on the ls output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not consciously parse out the output of `ls`, see [BashFAQ - Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), it could go wrong in a number of ways. Use the built-in glob expansion supported in the shell

```
for file in *_*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    mkdir -p "${file%%_*}" || { printf 'error creating dir\n' >&2; exit 1; }
    mv "$file" "${file%%_*}/${file##*_}"
done
```

The `"${file%%_*}` and `${file##*_}"` are parameter expansions syntices for extracting the earliest and farthest strings from a word given a delimiter, which in this case is `_`. See [Bash - Parameter expansion - substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal)